# How to mount Azure File share to support Symlinks on Azure file share with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, mount, symbolic-link, smb, azure

I need to use the Azure file share for deployments with Capistrano, the problem is that I don't seem to be able to create symlinks on the disk, which mounts as SMB.

I'm mounting the File Share on a Ubuntu server 14.04.

Here's the extract from my `/etc/fstab`:

```
//xxxxxx.file.core.windows.net/xxxxx /azure cifs serverino,sfu,vers=2.1,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,uid=xxxxx,username=xxxxxx,password=xxxxxxx
```

This is what I get when I try to create a symlink:

```
$ ln -s alfa file
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'file': File exists
```

How could I create a symlink on Azure File Share?

Thanks

Comment: Same problem here - would be very useful to get that answered.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

STackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64153628/alternative-for-symlink-for-azure-file-share

Details from Microsoft:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-linux-file-connection-problems#cannot-create-symbolic-links---ln-failed-to-create-symbolic-link-t-operation-not-supported

More useful links:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/UNIX_Extensions#Storing_symlinks_on_Windows_servers
https://blog.gripdev.xyz/2017/09/26/quick-how-to-mount-azure-files-shares-with-symlinks-support-on-ubuntu/

Best regards

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is really a link only answer. Please [edit] and include the relevant details form the links in your answer, else it may be deleted. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1133838)